# Killing PGIDs but proceses are respawning, how do I make it persistent?

Tags: linux, process, kill, ps

I ran `ps aux --forest -j` to see parent and child processes. Here is an example:

```
root      3744  3744  3744  0.0  0.2  77084  4160 ?        Ss   09:34   0:00 /usr/sbin/cupsd -f
lp        3747  3747  3744  0.0  0.1  63156  2236 ?        S    09:34   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus:// 
lp        3748  3748  3744  0.0  0.1  63156  2240 ?        S    09:34   0:00  \_ /usr/lib/cups/notifier/dbus dbus://
```

In the third column is the PGID. My goal is to kill all 3 of these PIDs by using the PGID of the parent, 3744. My command is -

```
pkill -TERM -g 3744
```

This works, however, the process respawns itself with new PIDs. How can I avoid this and make it persistent?

Comment: There's probably a service manager that is restarting cups when it dies. What is the output of `service cups status` ?

Comment: sudo service cups status
cups start/running, process 3844

Comment: I guess its safe to say if its backed a service or script that runs every so often the only way to make it persistent is to disable the service? Or remove it from the script?

Comment: You have a couple choices here. Is your goal to kill off the cups server and to not have it restarted ever? Restarted at the next reboot? Restarted only upon an explicit `service start` or equivalent command?

Comment: Since service handling is not quite standardized, the best solution may differ slightly depending on your distribution.  Can you add your distribution and its release number, such as `ubuntu 15.04`?

Comment: Killed and restarted at the next reboot, preferably without having to do anything to the service.   Ubuntu 14.04 3.13.0-32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're running Ubuntu 14.04, which uses [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html) as its init process. As we can see from looking at `/etc/init/cups.conf`, it has a `respawn` stanza, so by default when the cupsd process ends, another one will be started.

```
# kill -TERM -3390
# tail -1 /var/log/syslog
Aug  9 14:22:49 ubuntu kernel: [  283.270126] init: cups main process ended, respawning
```

You said you wanted the cupsd process tree killed, and restarted at the next reboot. To do this, you can use the `initctl stop` (or just `stop`) command:

```
# stop cups
cups stop/waiting
```

You may also want to stop `cups-browsed`, if you want all things associated with cups to stop.

This won't permanently disable the service. Upon reboot, the cups processes will be started.